# If else with rm Shell linux

Tags: linux, shell

I need help whith my problem.
I need make a shell script...

this it's my idea

```
if [ rm -r -f /directorie ]; then    
  code     
else    
  code    
fi
...
```

how I can?

Comment: Do you just want to change your condition to `if rm -rf /directory; then`?

Comment: The solution you just posted `if rm -r -f /directorie = true; then...` is not correct because this test will always equals to `true`, whether or not the directory existed and was deleted. Check out my answer, it may be a better fit for what you're looking for.

Comment: `rm -f` will always return `0` whether the command worked or not. Without `-f` it will write a message to `stderr` and return a non-zero value on error.

Comment: `if rm -r -f /directorie = true` does not do what you think it does. It will execute `rm` forcing a recursive deletion of the following: `/directorie`, `=`, and `true`. Since `rm -f` always return `0`, your code will never execute the `else` block.

Comment: Even if the that solution *were* correct, you should post it as an answer, not include it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This code may achieve what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -r /directorie > /dev/null 2>&1; rc="$?" 
if [ "$rc" -eq "0" ]; then
   # code here
else
   # code here
fi
```

Note: `rm -rf /directorie` (with the option `f`) would always return a return code = 0 (true), thus it is not suited for an `if` test.

**Edit**:  this answer can be condensed into a `bash` one-liner:

```
rm -r /home/owner/scripts > /dev/null 2>&1 && code here (true) || code here (false)
```

Comment: So what happens if the user has no permission to delete the directory? Checking if a directory exist and checking if a recursive delete of a directory succeeds are entirely two different things.

Comment: You're correct, thanks for pointing it out. First I thought that the directory test would be a very good proxy for what was being attempted, as (I thought) the only reason `rm -rf` would not delete a directory was if it did not exist. A dangerous assumption of mine! Sure, permissions, and maybe other things! I fixed the answer. Comments welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir=/directory
test -d "${dir}" && rm -rf "${dir}" && ! test -d "${dir}" && echo OK || echo NOK
```